# Opening Visual Studio brings up a login screen when I am already logged in Error Code 16000

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have a few different Microsoft accounts.
When I open VS2022 17.2.4 a Microsoft login screen pops up even though I am already logged into VS.
I can just close the screen as VS is already logged in, but it is annoying.

I have tried updating my VS license.

[image: login screen]

If I click the bottom 3 dots I come across error code 16000 as described at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-keeps-recurrently-asking-to-login/1284416

I am running Windows  10 ver 21H2

I am logged into windows with the same email as I am using to login to VS.

The problem started a few months ago.

Comment: I had same problem, I'm logged in, but login pops up. I have vs 2022 17.2.5 community edition running windows 10 Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044

Comment: I guess, it is happening because you have got multiple accounts there? so maybe remove the unused account from there?

Comment: Same here. Very annoying. I DO have multiple accounts registered...